# IntelliJ TestNG Maven Test automation project structure

Tags: maven, selenium, intellij-idea, automation, testng

i'm thinking about test automation structure using selenium, intelliJ ide, testng and maven. What You think about below:

[image: Selenium test structure]

I used one project and many directories beacuse i want to have just one pom file. If You could help me with testng file. How it should look like if i want to run all tests which are available in all "Tests" directories? What means click run and fire up all tests with "Test" testng annotations. Helpers, pages and tests directories exist becasue i will want to do this with POM & Page Factory.

@Sid below my pom. My testng.xml is empty currently because i do not know how to configure it to run all what i have in "Tests" directories. 
Thank you for reply.
[image]

My tests are just examples with beforetests, test and aftertest annotations. Nothing to admire ;)

Comment: Share what you have attempted with the pom, testng.xml and the tests @Miho

Comment: @Sid: this structure is ok for You or i should split it on 4 different maven projects? 1 project = 1 module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

I would assume your helper class is goin to have common functions. Also, depending on the size of your modules you may want to create more sub-module folders. You can also add a commons folder which contains generic steps and methods.

Now, if your modules are deployed completely independent of each other, you want to take a call on whether the code should reside with the app code or in one place like you have.

The structure would work out fine either ways. To run all the tests you need to include the folders / classes path in your testng files. IDE/Maven/testng dont care about your folder structure so long as you include all the paths correctly. Check out https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-5-suite-test/ for how to do that.